# How to iterate an array just retrieved from a hash?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to iterate an array which I just retrieved from a hash:

```
my %h = (
  'z' => ['1', '2', '3'],
  'b' => ['x', 'y'],
);
my @a = $h{'b'};
foreach my $k (@a) {
  print "[$k]";
}
```

However, instead of `[x][y]` it prints:

```
[ARRAY(0x7fc6f2825de8)]
```

Why?

Comment: `print @$k`. `$k` is a reference to an array, not an array. You have to dereference it.

Comment: It seems you should (re-)read [perldata](https://perldoc.pl/perldata) and [perlref](https://perldoc.pl/perlref), given your recent questions.

Comment: @yegor256: You need to read (and understand) the [Data Structures Cookbook](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc).

Comment: Too late, I have already written my Perl program and hope to never see this beautiful language ever again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since:

```
'b' => ['x', 'y']
```

Then:

```
my @a = $h{'b'};
```

Is the same as

```
my @a = ['x', 'y'];
```

Which is an array where the first element of the array is another array. Its a two-dimensional array.

If you want to print the array in one go, you have to dereference the second level:

```
print @$k;
```

If you do not want it to be two-dimensional, you can use dereference it when assigning:

```
my @a = @{ $h{'b'} };
```

Be aware that this will not deep copy your hash values.

Or better yet, just copy the reference:

```
my $aref = $h{'b'};

for my $k (@$aref) {
    print "[$k]";
}
```

Comment: I don't want to print the array in one go. I want to iterate (as the title of my question says). Is it possible?

Comment: By the way, I don't want my array to be "two-dimentional". I expect `"x", "y"` to be a normal one-dimentional array. Something is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: The hash value that you assign is not an array, but a reference to an array, that is the issue. But it is fine, as long as you remember to dereference correctly.